# Get free disk space for different servers with separate credentials

Tags: windows, powershell, csv

I'm trying to query Disk space info on Grid box and Export it to CSV.

I was able to use Marc Weisel's script to make it use different credentials. I used computers.csv

to store the computer name and referenced credentials. This is working although the problem I'm facing is that Grid box opens for all the servers mentioned in the csv.

I want to view all disk space information on the same grid box.

Below are my script and module I'm using

```
    Import-Module D:\get.psm1
Import-Module D:\out-CSV.psm1
$ComputerList = Import-Csv -Path d:\Computers.csv;
#$servers = 'laptop-pc','laptop-pc','laptop-pc'
$CredentialList = @{
    Cred1 = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList 'laptop-pc\laptop', (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'tamboli' -AsPlainText -Force);
    #Cred2 = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList 'tnt\administrator', (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'Atlantic12' -AsPlainText -Force);
    }
foreach ($computer in $ComputerList ) 
{
Get-DiskFree -ComputerName $Computer.Name -Credential $CredentialList[$Computer.Credential] -Format | ? { $_.Type -like '*fixed*' } | select * -ExcludeProperty Type |
}
```

**get.ps1**

```
function Get-DiskFree
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param 
    (
        [Parameter(Position=0,
                   ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [Alias('hostname')]
        [Alias('cn')]
        [string[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,

        [Parameter(Position=1,
                   Mandatory=$false)]
        [Alias('runas')]
        [System.Management.Automation.Credential()]$Credential =
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty,

        [Parameter(Position=2)]
        [switch]$Format
    )

    BEGIN
    {
        function Format-HumanReadable 
        {
            param ($size)
            switch ($size) 
            {
                {$_ -ge 1PB}{"{0:#.#'P'}" -f ($size / 1PB); break}
                {$_ -ge 1TB}{"{0:#.#'T'}" -f ($size / 1TB); break}
                {$_ -ge 1GB}{"{0:#.#'G'}" -f ($size / 1GB); break}
                {$_ -ge 1MB}{"{0:#.#'M'}" -f ($size / 1MB); break}
                {$_ -ge 1KB}{"{0:#'K'}" -f ($size / 1KB); break}
                default {"{0}" -f ($size) + "B"}
            }
        }

        $wmiq = 'SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE Size != Null AND DriveType >= 2'
    }

    PROCESS
    {
        foreach ($computer in $ComputerName)
        {
            try
            {
                if ($computer -eq $env:COMPUTERNAME)
                {
                    $disks = Get-WmiObject -Query $wmiq `
                             -ComputerName $computer -ErrorAction Stop
                }
                else
                {
                    $disks = Get-WmiObject -Query $wmiq `
                             -ComputerName $computer -Credential $Credential `
                             -ErrorAction Stop
                }

                if ($Format)
                {
                    # Create array for $disk objects and then populate
                    $diskarray = @()
                    $disks | ForEach-Object { $diskarray += $_ }

                    $diskarray | Select-Object @{n='Name';e={$_.SystemName}}, 
                        @{n='Vol';e={$_.DeviceID}},
                        @{n='Size';e={Format-HumanReadable $_.Size}},
                        @{n='Used';e={Format-HumanReadable `
                        (($_.Size)-($_.FreeSpace))}},
                        @{n='Avail';e={Format-HumanReadable $_.FreeSpace}},
                        @{n='Use%';e={[int](((($_.Size)-($_.FreeSpace))`
                        /($_.Size) * 100))}},
                        @{n='FS';e={$_.FileSystem}},
                        @{n='Type';e={$_.Description}}
                }
                else 
                {
                    foreach ($disk in $disks)
                    {
                        $diskprops = @{'Volume'=$disk.DeviceID;
                                   'Size'=$disk.Size;
                                   'Used'=($disk.Size - $disk.FreeSpace);
                                   'Available'=$disk.FreeSpace;
                                   'FileSystem'=$disk.FileSystem;
                                   'Type'=$disk.Description
                                   'Computer'=$disk.SystemName;}

                        # Create custom PS object and apply type
                        $diskobj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject `
                                   -Property $diskprops
                        $diskobj.PSObject.TypeNames.Insert(0,'BinaryNature.DiskFree')

                        Write-Output $diskobj
                    }
                }
            }
            catch 
            {
                # Check for common DCOM errors and display "friendly" output
                switch ($_)
                {
                    { $_.Exception.ErrorCode -eq 0x800706ba } `
                        { $err = 'Unavailable (Host Offline or Firewall)'; 
                            break; }
                    { $_.CategoryInfo.Reason -eq 'UnauthorizedAccessException' } `
                        { $err = 'Access denied (Check User Permissions)'; 
                            break; }
                    default { $err = $_.Exception.Message }
                }
                Write-Warning "$computer - $err"
            } 
        }
    }

    END {}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to append the result of Get-DiskFree to an array in the loop, and pipe that result to the Grid View from outside your loop:

```
foreach ($computer in $ComputerList ) 
{
    $result += Get-DiskFree -ComputerName $Computer.Name -Credential $CredentialList[$Computer.Credential] -Format | ? { $_.Type -like '*fixed*' } | select * -ExcludeProperty Type 
}

$result | Out-GridView
```

Or, better yet, pipe the result from outside the Foreach-Object loop:

```
$ComputerList | % {
    Get-DiskFree -ComputerName $_.Name -Credential $CredentialList[$_.Credential] -Format | ? { $_.Type -like '*fixed*' } | select * -ExcludeProperty Type 
} | Out-GridView
```